# Get user's exact location

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a website in which i need to get the records closest to users location. I don't want to get the input from user for his location. How can I get the exact user location to get the records nearer to his location?

Comment: You need to do geolocation if you don't want the input from user. You can use this as reference. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/

Answer (score 1):

What data are you wanting to retrieve? The coordinates? Address?

You could use plain javascript to get the coordinates:

```
// check to see if the browser supports geolocation
if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showCoordData);
}

function showCoordData(data){
    // in data.coords you'll have latitude, longitude, accuracy,
    // altitudeAccuracy, heading, and speed
    console.log(data.coords);
}
```

If you're wanting to get the street address, city, state, etc. from the coordinates you'd probably be better off using Google Maps or Bing Maps API. (I'd try Google first obviously).

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427611.aspx